# How can I mock behaviour of new object created inside static Main?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, ibatis

IS there any way I can mock behaviour of an object created inside my Test class static method? Like, I have class like below:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext cxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
      SomeMapper map = cxt.getBean(SomeMapper.class);
      map.getData();
    }
}
```

The mapper 'SomeMapper' is ibatis query mapper for fetching data from DB. Can I right a test class for this method using Mockito framework? Or can just mock behaviour of mapper class or ApplicationContext class?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use other approach. If you need configure the application with the values, use `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyCustomConfiguration{
    
    @Autowired
    SomeMapper someMapper;

    //your code
}
```

In this approach you can mock the mapper in the test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyCustomConfigurationTest{
    
    @Mock
    SomeMapper someMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    MyCustomConfiguration configuration;

    //your tests
}
```

Also you have a second option if you just need execute some logic. You can implement `ApplicationRunner` interface. This is executed on startup and you can inject the beans as a normal spring component. The code ir really similar so I'm not going to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to test your `main` method, lift the actual logic into a standard class and test that instead.  Leave your `main` method to handle things that are explicitly concerned with launching your app.  For example, you might break it up like this:

```
class MapperRunner {
    private SomeMapper mapper;

    public class MapperRunner(SomeMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void runMapping() {
        mapper.getData();
    }    
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext cxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        SomeMapper map = cxt.getBean(SomeMapper.class);
        new MapperRunner(map).runMapping();
    }
}
```

With just a single method this definitely looks like overkill, but presumably your actual code does something more complex than this.

Comment: Yes, I was considering the same. Does that means there is no other way?

Comment: It doesn't mean there's no other way, but to me it's the cleanest way to do it.  You should aim to have only code that is related to bootstrapping in your main method to make it more flexible, and usually more testable = more flexible